# \span as a math operator

Tags: macros, naming

I'd like `\span` to be a math operator (for the [span](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span) of a set of vectors), but apparently it's already a TeX command. What do you guys recommend I do instead? (I don't really want a strange capital `\Span`, or some other odd variant... but I'm guessing it's a bad idea to redefine `\span`?)

Comment: As a general practice, I always use upper case to define my own macros. So I use `\SPAN`. This avoids collision with the internal macros. Since all such macros that I define are upper case, it does not appear strange `:-)`.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes, it's a bad idea: `\span` is a primitive command used in `\multicolumn`.

Actually `\span` appears only once in the LaTeX kernel, so it's possible to say

```
\makeatletter
\let\@@span\span
\def\sp@n{\@@span\omit\advance\@multicnt\m@ne}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\span}{...}
```

but other packages might rely on the primitive meaning of `\span`. If you like to live dangerously…

There is indeed an important package that relies on `\span` and it is **amsmath**, which in one of its most important routines uses that primitive. When LaTeX3 will be released, all primitive commands will have received new names and LaTeX3 packages will not be using `\span` anymore; till then, choose another name such as `\Span` or `\vspan`.

Comment: Seems it has more quibbles with `amsmath`: redefining `\span` gets "Missing # inserted in alignment preamble." and then a bunch of "Extra alignment tab". Perhaps this is a terrible idea after all. Suggestions on naming for a new command?

Comment: (That's when I try to use the `align*` or any other `amsmath` environment.)

Comment: @jtbandes: Perhaps add more context to the macro name: `\vecspan` or `\vectorspan`.

Comment: Hmm, it seems another advantage of future LaTeX3

Comment: @LeoLiu Yes, this is surely an advantage: primitives won't be accessible by their original names (unless one uses `\primitive`, with its new name, of course); there will be less risks of redefining something important.

Comment: Your command gives the new command in italics if `\renewcommand{\span}{span}`. How can you have it without italics?

Comment: @Masi *Don't* redefine `\span` to begin with. Then do `\DeclareMathOperator{\Span}{span}`

Answer (score 25):

Since `\span` is already a well-established macro, it can't be a good idea to re-use the word for a new command. Are `\spn` and `\Span` really that bad as alternatives to `\span`? The following MWE, which uses the `amsmath` package and its `DeclareMathOperator` command, illustrates the usage of the macro called `\spn`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\DeclareMathOperator{\spn}{span}
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\begin{document}
Let $\vec{e}_i = (0,\dots,0,1,0,\dots,0)'$ be an $n\times 1$ column 
vector with $1$ in the $i$-th position and $0$ in all others. Then 
$\spn\{\vec{e}_1,\vec{e}_2,\dots,\vec{e}_n\} = \mathbb{R}^n$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Consider using `spann` or `spanset`, I would prefer the latter with a short macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\DeclareMathOperator{\spann}{span}
\newcommand\spanset[1]{\ensuremath\spann(#1)}
\begin{document}
\[
\spann(S) = \spann(v_1,\dots,v_r) = \{ {\lambda _1 v_1  +  \dots  + \lambda _r v_r \mid \lambda _1 , \dots ,\lambda _r  \in \mathbf{K}} \}
\]

\[
\spanset{S}=\spanset{v_1,\dots,v_r}= \{ {\lambda _1 v_1  +  \dots  + \lambda _r v_r \mid \lambda _1 , \dots ,\lambda _r  \in \mathbf{K}} \}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
\operatorname{span}
```

This works well.

Comment: welcome to TeX.SX! Explaining a bit more about this solution or showing a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) would greatly improve the answer.